# jQuery zoom in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create an effect on an advent calendar (a bit out of season, I know).

In short, when I open a door I want to create a zooming in/warp effect to give the illusion you are being entered into the door.

I have looked into the similar:

http://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/GKflw
http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/jQueryZoom/jQueryZoom.html

My biggest issue is that I need to ensure this works in IE8! Yes, annoying. And yes I understand my limitations. CSS3 out of the equation, however I need to get as close to this effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What about using transform: Scale() for modern browsers and the zoom property for IE. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531189(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @PatrickGunderson unfortunately not!

Comment: It's 2014. I would never recommend using Flash for web-related... anythings. @PatrickGunderson

Comment: @kehrk If you're committed to fully supporting a technology from 2009 then your 2014 argument is invalid since you don't have the tools from 2014 in your arsenal (CSS3). You should be open to using a technology that was developed to plug the holes from 2009 technology, or you should be open to only partially supporting older tech (IE8).

Comment: When your client uses IE8 - you do not have a choice but to be picky about what tools you use.